# Install meter box on existing steel siding

Tags: electrical, siding, steel

I need to install 2 electrical boxes on existing steel siding.  One box is a 13" meter box (ringless lever), and while I'm at it I want to leave room to install a solar panel disconnect switch box for a project next spring.

[image: Likely meter location]

I'm afraid if I surface mount the boxes over the siding, it will look like crap.  But to remove the siding from the top down seems like a lot of work; the contractors who installed it did a good job (even rivets along the top).  There doesn't seem to be any siding seams along this wall.  Difficult to see in the picture, but there is concrete block wall below the siding for about 6 inches.

I could also install to the left edge of this wall, it won't look any easier.  If I install on the back wall of the garage, there are at least some seams, but some are pretty long.

[Power Company meter guidelines](https://www.dakotaelectric.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/DEAElectricServiceManualFINAL_Section3.pdf)

The main panel needs to go pretty much behind this pictured wall due to obstacles inside the garage, but I can be flexible exactly where the meter is to some extent (external conduit runs within reason).

I've given some thought to putting them to the right of the door as that dimension is almost exactly the width of the meter box (even with the downspout in place).  If needed, I do have some extra siding panels and J channels / trim the contractor left from the siding job a few years ago.

Can anyone think of other options?

Comment: Remember the meter location decides the service panel location (unless the meter includes a main breaker), and you'll be running a lot of cables from the service panel.  To the right of the door makes no sense, you would not be able to route that many cables away from there without overcrowding.

Comment: What size of a service are you dealing with here?  Also, do you have outbuildings on your property, or plans for outbuildings for that matter, and is the service overhead or underground?

Comment: No outbuildings, nor any planned.  Installing new 200A buried entrance.

Comment: I take it there are no plans for accessory dwelling units or such either?

Comment: Single dwelling

Comment: Do you already have the main panel fitted, or are you going to be installing or procuring/installing a new one yourself?

Comment: Also, how do you plan to fit the solar feed into this setup?

Comment: Adding new main panel.   Planning to source tap PVC prior to main.

Answer (score 1):

These questions got way off the intended topic.   My question was about the physical mounting of the meter box,  mounting blocks,  how to remove needed siding,  etc.

Over the weekend I carefully removed from and believe I can remove the siding panels I need without destroying my siding.